# What art style is this?

Tags: vector, style, art

There is an style I found at it looks incredible and beautiful, i want to utilize this art and make it in illustrator so I was wondering what type of art style is this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71fLFOjruFc

Here's a still frame from the animation

[image]

Comment: "stylized vector art" I guess. Not everything has a particular name. Anyway how a name would help you? To learn the style analyze it and start to draw in similar manner.

Comment: Monochromatic is really all that fits. Yeah it's *probably* vector based, but that in itself isn't really a "style".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a name for this specific kind of artwork. This is a monochromatic, stylized artwork. It may be vector, but the gradients and some detail makes me think it was actually made in Photoshop. One of the best ways to learn how to do something like this is to simply mimic it, you’ll learn a whole lot about the style just trying to make it match what you see. Then you can take what you learned and do your own designs!

Comment: It's an animation, so probably not Photoshop. More likely AfterEffects or some other animation software. It's possible to add gradients and textures in vector work too.  Welcome to GDSE by the way. Keep contributing!  I've given you an upvote to help with your rep score.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!